# Unable to click a wpsToolBarLink link in the "IBM Navigator for i" browser using Protractor

Tags: hyperlink, protractor

I am new to Protractor and attempting to click the "**Logout**" wpsToolBarLink link that exists within the HTML shown below. xpath, cssContainingText, partialLinkText and linkText have not been able to identify the element. Waiting by using Protractor.ExpectedConditions also fails as the element is never found.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```html
<body>
<div role="main">
<table border="0" height="35" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wpsToolBar" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;" role="presentation">
    <tbody><tr style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
      
      
        <td align="left" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
            <img style="vertical-align: top;" alt="Integrated Solutions Console" title="Integrated Solutions Console" src="/ibm/console/images/iscbannerLeft-.gif">
        </td>
        
        <td align="right" width="40%" nowrap="" class="wpsWelcomeText" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;padding-left=20px;">
        Welcome #JDEQA8
        </td>

        <td align="left" width="40%" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
            <div id="bannerMessageArea"><table id="TargetSystem" width="100%"><tbody><tr><th align="center"> <font color="black">  Target system:            <b>hqd400
</b></font></th></tr></tbody></table></div></td>        

        <td class="wpsToolBarLink" nowrap="" width="3%" style="text-align:center;">
            <a title="Help" href="http://hqd400:2004/ibm/console/help.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
            Help 
            </a>
        </td>
        
        <td align="center" style="width:10px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
            <img style="vertical-align: middle;" title="Icon separator" alt="Icon separator" src="/ibm/console/images/toolbar_separator.gif">
        </td>
        
        <td class="wpsToolBarLink" nowrap="" width="3%" style="text-align:center;">
            <a title="Logout" href="http://hqd400:2004/ibm/console/logout.do?XSS=I4FYWMe_YIcC7cmnTrUH4_y" onclick="javascript:cleancookies();return false" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;">
              Logout 
            </a>
        </td>
        
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" style="padding-left:10px;">
            <img style="vertical-align: top;" alt="IBM" title="IBM" src="/ibm/console/images/iscbanner-mosaic.gif">
        </td>
            
        

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Failed also with `element(by.linkText('Logout'));` ?

Have you tried with css? since I see its the second  element with the same class, try this:
`element.all(by.css('.wpsToolBarLink a')).get(1);`

Another css you can try:
`element(by.css('[title="Logout"]'));`

Which expected conditions are you using in this case? I believe a `presenceOf` followed by a `elementToBeClickable` would be ideal

Comment: element(by.css('[title="Logout"]'));  results in 
 Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [title="Logout"])

Comment: element.all(by.css('.wpsToolBarLink a')).get(1).click(); results in
 Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .wpsToolBarLink a)

Comment: element(by.linkText('Logout')).click();  results in
 Failed: No element found using locator: By(link text, Logout)

Comment: var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.cssContainingText('.wpsToolBarLink', 'Logout')), 5000, "element is not clickable")).then(function() {
      element(by.cssContainingText('.wpsToolBarLink', 'Logout')).click();
  });   resulted in this....    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Comment: @Andrew you have double asterix around your "logout" button. Is it commented or what? If yes it cannot be reached

Comment: Double asterisk (I thought) was the StackOverflow notation for BOLD.  The asterisks do not belong.  I have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to click on that parent class element?

```
element(by.className('wpsToolBarLink'));
```

you might be able to avoid on clicking the button, other thing is, the element that you are trying to click might not be loaded when the click goes off, i suggest trying to wait before with

```
browser.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: note: if you'd post the actual e2e code, it'd be much easier to answer